# How do I select/call an Instantiated GameObject within an array without usind index

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a random grid generation base for game map and I'm kinda stuck at how do I call an instantiated object based on their in game coordinates (not Vector3).

This is my hex generation script:

```
public HexCell cellPrefab;
HexCell[] cells;

void CreateCell (int x, int z, int i) {

    Vector3 position;
    position.x = (x + z * 0.5f - z / 2) * (HexMetrics.innerRadius * 2f);
    position.y = 0f;
    position.z = z * (HexMetrics.outerRadius * 1.5f);

    HexCell cell = cells[i] = Instantiate<HexCell>(cellPrefab);
    cell.coordinates = HexCoordinates.FromOffsetCoordinates(x, z);
}
```

I can call the object fine using index of objects' array but I can't wrap my head around the idea of calling it based on its given coordinates.

This is how I give them coordinates based on each hex position;

```
public class HexCell : MonoBehaviour {
public HexCoordinates coordinates;
}

public struct HexCoordinates {

[SerializeField]
private int x, z;

public int X {
    get { return x; }
}

public int Y {
    get { return -X - Z; }
}

public int Z {
    get { return z; }
}

public HexCoordinates (int x, int z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.z = z;
}

public static HexCoordinates FromOffsetCoordinates (int x, int z) {
    return new HexCoordinates(x - z / 2, z);
}
}
```

So how do I call/select desired hex based on HexCell coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how do I call/select desired hex based on HexCell coordinates?

This is easy to do since you used `int` instead of `float` to represent the coordinate. Just loop over the `cells` array. In each loop, access the `coordinates` variable from the `HexCell`  component then compare x, `y` and z values. If they match, return the current `HexCell` in the loop. If not, simply return `null`. You can also do this with `linq` but avoid it.

Your cell array:

```
HexCell[] cells;
```

Get `HexCell` from coordinate:

```
HexCell getHexCellFromCoordinate(int x, int y, int z)
{
    //Loop thorugh each HexCell
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
    {
        HexCoordinates hc = cells[i].coordinates;

        //Check if coordinate matches then return it
        if ((hc.X == x) && (hc.Y == y) && (hc.Z == z))
        {
            return cells[i];
        }
    }

    //No match. Return null
    return null;
}
```

Since the coordinate is in `int` instead of `float`, you can also use [`Vector3Int`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3Int.html)*(Requires Unity 2017.2 and above)* to represent them instead of x, y and z. Note that this is different from [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html).

```
HexCell getHexCellFromCoordinate(Vector3Int coord)
{
    //Loop thorugh each HexCell
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
    {
        HexCoordinates hc = cells[i].coordinates;

        //Check if coordinate matches then return it
        if ((hc.X == coord.x) && (hc.Y == coord.y) && (hc.Z == coord.z))
        {
            return cells[i];
        }
    }

    //No match. Return null
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use some built-in functions to make it more readable.

```
HexCell getHexCellFromCoordinate(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return cells.FirstOrDefault(
        cell =>
           cell.x == x &&
           cell.y == y &&
           cell.z == z
    );
}

HexCell getHexCellFromCoordinate(Vector3Int coord)
{
    return cells.FirstOrDefault(cell =>
         cell.x == coord.x &&
         cell.y == coord.y &&
         cell.z == coord.z
    );
}
```

It's worth noting, since I'm not sure where you'll be needing to find the cells, that `FirstOrDefault` makes heap allocations and therefore invoking it too often on too large of a list (as in tens of thousands of times per frame, and/or against tens of thousands of objects) it could result in undesired garbage collections, which *may* cause a stutter in your application, and that stutter *may* be noticeable if combined with other code that uses heap allocations willy-nilly.

So as a general rule, start with something simple. If your application starts to slow down or take up too much memory, go back and optimize starting with the hottest (least performant) code. You can use a profiler to help you find those spots. But please, don't riddle your code with for loops just to save some extra cpu cycles.

Comment: It's doing the-same thing in my answer except that it is using linq. I clearly mentioned in my answer that it can be done with linq but urged OP to avoid that due to performance reasons. Unity is a game engine not a Windows Form program. Some C# features/API should be avoided unless if they are called less often.

Comment: As I'm gonna use this at the start of my map generation process, there should not be any issue with performance. I wonder what do you mean by saving few cpu cycle by using for loop. Is there any other way if I need to cycle through an array looking for specific item?

Comment: You can certainly use a for loop. At its core, that's what FirstOrDefault is doing. The only difference is FirstOrDefault may provide better readability at a negligible cost of performance or memory consumption. If no-one has to read your code again (including you), it matters very little which you use. But if someone else were to read your code, what's the fastest route to comprehension? A for loop with an index access and early return with the potential to return null, or 'cells.FirstOrDefault(cell => cell.position == targetPosition)'. It's up to you. I just wanted you to know some options.